# PlayOnLinux error while using Internet Explorer

Tags: playonlinux, ie

While using Internet Explorer, the browser is getting stuck, and a PlayOnLinux window is appearing with this message: `[POL_Wine] Error: Wine seems to have crashed.` Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Repair wine or Reinstall it........because it was crashed and currently PlayOnLinux supporting some games for GNU/Linux so be aware for that.

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install wine1.6

sudo apt-get -f install
```